# Function on all links of an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

on a page I have an iframe and, on head, this function (based on Jquery)

```
*$(window).load(function(){     
    $('#framelearning').contents().find('a').click(function(event) {
        alert("clicked!");
    }); 
});
```

It works fine... but if an user click on a link and changes the url of this iframe, It not works. The function works only for the first page loaded.
It's possible modify this function to work with all pages loaded on the iframe?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some HTML to look at, as well? Where is this jQuery being loaded, in the outer page (the one containing the iFrame) or the page being loaded into the iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load()` is only loaded once, so that's why it wouldn't do anything when the iFrame src is changed.

Ideally, what you should do is encapsulate your functionality so that it can be reused, but even then, I'm not sure if you can hook into an iFrame's onload event.

Something like this is what I'd imagine:

```
function captureLinks() {
    $('#framelearning').contents().find('a').click(function(event) {
        alert("clicked!");
    });
}

$("#myiframe").on("load",captureLinks);
```

Without more details from you in regard to your HTML, it's hard to say if this will really address the problem you're trying to solve.